# How to stop doxygen searching for third party headers

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I am now following [this document](https://majewsky.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/tip-of-the-day-cmake-and-doxygen/) to generate doxygen html file within cmake script.  However, I found a big problem. I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
header.h
#include "third_party_header.h"
/**
* explanation of head_fun function 
*/
int head_fun();
```

In this header.h file, when generating documentation I only want to document functions within the file. However, when running doxygen, it seemed that it tried to search for the "third_party_header.h" for generating documents. In my case, it did succeed as the "third_party_header.h" is not in the search path of doxygen. Any ideas I can do to tell doxygen stopping searching for third party headers?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by accident, and it seemed that if I disable CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING, then everything goes on well. But I have no clue why this can stop Doxygen searching for third party head files. If I understand well, when CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING is enabled, it will compile all the source codes within the denoted Doxygen input directory first before generating documentations.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.